# Existence of bound states in 3D Yukawa potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation

For a 3D Yukawa potential

$$ V(r) = - \lambda { e^{-Mr} \over r}. $$

[Bargmann's upper bound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bargmann's_limit) can be read as *necessary* condition for the existence of at least one bound state; we want $N_l>1$ and from $$\int r V(r) > (2 l +1) N_l$$ we had (for the $l=0$ wave)

$$\frac \lambda M > 1$$

(in units where $1=2m=\hbar$). And it looks a bit poor limit in this case. Is there a better bound, preferably a *sufficient and necessary* condition, or at least a good numerical approximation?

Comment: I thought that Bargmann's bound is the best bound one may get, the exact condition!

Comment: Hmm @LubosMotl I believe it is the best bound for general V(r), but that for specific potentials it can be possible to do better (or not; as some potentials saturate it).

Comment: @Qmechanic thanks for the edition. I am going to put the "Bohr model" answer too, to clarify further the question.

Answer (score 1):

Let me do a draft of the "Bohr model" answer that I think is failing in some O(1) factor, but still clarifies further the question. It is unclear how to find a bound for the existence of a bound state, but at least we can try for onset of the existence of a local minimum in the potential.

In Bohr's way, model states are simply the equilibrium between force and centrifugal term
$$ V'(r) = {L^2 \over m r^3}$$

For enough nice -not a technical term... just nice in a lot of ways!- potentials, as we vary their parameters, the LHS will become equal to the RHS in some point, but furthermore they will be tangent. If you prefer, the function we could call $f'(r) \equiv RHS - LHS$ is everywhere nonzero when there is no bound state, and then at the onset it not only has $f'(r)=0$ but also $f''(r)=0$. So we consider also this second condition
$$ V''(r) = {-3 L^2 \over m r^4}$$

which solves to either $r=0$ (and nothing can be said then, if the bound state starts  from zero radius) or 
$$ r V''(r) + 3 V'(r) =0$$

Note that the "jump-in radius" is going to be in any case independent of $L$ and of the coupling constant. Particularly for the Yukawa potential

$$V'(r)= \lambda {e^{-Mr}\over r^2} (Mr +1)$$
$$V''(r)=- 2 \lambda {e^{-Mr}\over r^2} (\frac 12 M^2r^2 + Mr +1)$$

So the equation is $M^2r^2 - Mr -1 =0$ and it solves to 
$$Mr= \frac 12 (1 +\sqrt 5 )$$

Now, imposing this in the first equation we get, if we believe Bohr's $L=n\hbar$
$$ \lambda {e^{-\phi}} (\phi +1)  = {(n\hbar)^2 \over m r}$$
and the onset condition for the existence of this state is, setting $n=1$ and QM units $\hbar=1=2m$,
$$ {\lambda\over M} = {2 e^{+\phi}\over \phi (\phi +1)} \approx 2.38$$

I am not sure if this is right; as I said, there could be the case that the bound state orbit originates at $r=0$ as we vary the parameters of the potential, or I could have missed some of the  -huge- differences between Bohr models and Schrödinger solution. We could also believe to Pauli's $L=\sqrt{l(l+1)}\hbar$. Also, note that this is really the onset for the extreme of the radial effective potential; what happens really at this point is an inflexion point which as we move $\lambda$, separates in a maximum outwards and a minimum inwards; eventually the minimum becomes a resonance and after crossing to negative values of energy it can be a bound state. But as we have really solved only for $l > 0$ I am afraid the bound is for the existence of the second state, not for the lowest energy one.

Comment: Lurking in numerical literature, it seems that 1.68 is a well known bound happening during computer simulations,  (and already from Hulthen times). So this calculation is out by an $O(\sqrt 2)$ factor.

Comment: Googling around: I have found $\lambda {e^{-\phi}} (\phi +1)  = {L^2 \over m r}$ in slide 23 of a talk of Sean Tulin http://research.dsu.edu/cetup/documents/2013-talks/dark-matter/DM-05-SeanTulin.pdf about Dark Matter. And a  role of $\phi$ in Yukawa onsets is mentioned in http://arxiv.org/abs/0811.0287v1 but it is unclear if it is the same method.

Answer (score 1):

Bennett, Herbert S. "Upper Limits for the Number of Bound States Associated with the Yukawa Potential" *Journal of Research of the National Bureau of Standards*,
Vol. 86, No.5, September-October 1981 ([PDF](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/086/jresv86n5p503_A1b.pdf)):

> The number of bound-state solutions of the Schrodinger equation for
>   the screened Coulomb potential (Yukawa potential), $-(C/r) \exp(-\alpha
> > r)$, occurs frequently in theoretical discussions concerning, for
>   example, gas discharges, nuclear physics, and semiconductor physics.
>   The number of bound states is a function of $(C/\alpha)$. Three upper
>   limits for the number of bound states associated with the Yukawa
>   potential are evaluated and compared. These three limits are those
>   given by Bargmann, Schwinger, and Lieb. **In addition, the Sobolev
>   inequality states that whenever $(C/\alpha) < 1.65$ no bound state
>   occurs.** This agrees to within a few percent of the numerical
>   calcuiations of Bonch-Bruevich and Glasko. The Bargmann and Lieb
>   limits and the Sobolev inequality are substantially easier to evaluate
>   than the Schwinger limit. Among the three limits, **the Schwinger limit
>   gives the most restrictive limit for the existence of only one bound
>   state and, therefore, is the best one to use for the approach to no
>   binding, i.e., $1.65 < (C/\alpha) < 1.98$**. The Lieb limit is the best
>   among the three when $(C/\alpha) > 1.98$. The Bargmann limit is the
>   least restrictive.

(Emphasis mine.)

For more details, this may also be useful:

Brau, Fabian and Calogero, Francesco.  "[Upper and lower limits on the number of bound states in a central potential](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0305-4470/36/48/008/meta)". *Journal of Physics A: Mathematical and General*, Volume 36, Number 48, 19 November 2003.